# Entity Class with BigDecimal and not Long - Hibernate tools generated

Tags: hibernate, entity, long-integer, bigdecimal

Entity Class with BigDecimal and not Long

My entity classes are gereneated with Hibernate tools. Unfortunately some 'long' values become 'BigDecimal' numbers (Column: AGE, BIRTHDATE), but not all of them (Column: ID)!

Why is this happening and how should I fix this?

A table in my Oracle database: User

```
    Column    -   Type   - Decimal Digits - Column Sizes
    ----------+----------+----------------+-------------
    ID        - NUMBER   -     0          - 10
    AGE       - NUMBER   -     0          - 38
    BIRTHDATE - NUMBER   -     0          - 38
    FIRSTNAME - VARCHAR2 -   <null>       - 32
```

Using Hibernate Tools to generate Entity Classes (POJO)

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 0)
private long id;

@Column(name = "AGE", precision = 38, scale = 0)
private BigDecimal age;

@Column(name = "BIRTHDATE", precision = 38, scale = 0)
private BigDecimal birthdate;

@Column(name = "FIRSTNAME", length = 32)
private String firstname;
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think it is because your AGE and BRITHDATE columns are 38 column size, maximum number 'long' can have is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 which is 19 size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate tools can be configured to ***customize the type mapping***.
Specify in the reveng.xml all mappings (see screenshot).
Translate any JDBC type to any Hibernate type and run your generator again.

*reveng.xml mapping configuration:*

[image: reveng.xml mapping configuration]

*Use this reveng.xml in your generator:*

[image: use this reveng.xml in your generator]